# Perl regex for matching a perl BLOCK

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, pattern-matching

How can I match a multiline block in the following statements, given the blocks does not nest each other or itself:

```
       if (EXPR) BLOCK
       if (EXPR) BLOCK else BLOCK
       if (EXPR) BLOCK elsif (EXPR) BLOCK ... else BLOCK
       unless (EXPR) BLOCK
       unless (EXPR) BLOCK else BLOCK
       unless (EXPR) BLOCK elsif (EXPR) BLOCK ... else BLOCK
       LABEL while (EXPR) BLOCK
       LABEL while (EXPR) BLOCK continue BLOCK
       LABEL until (EXPR) BLOCK
       LABEL until (EXPR) BLOCK continue BLOCK
       LABEL for (EXPR; EXPR; EXPR) BLOCK
       LABEL foreach VAR (LIST) BLOCK
       LABEL foreach VAR (LIST) BLOCK continue BLOCK
       LABEL BLOCK continue BLOCK
```

If this cannot be done with regex, is a there a state machine capable doing so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't try to parse perl yourself.  If you really need to, use [PPI](http://p3rl.org/PPI), which does a decent job.

```
use PPI;
my $source = 'LABEL: { print "block" } continue { print "cont block" }';
my $doc = PPI::Document->new(\$source);
my $blocks = $doc->find("PPI::Structure::Block");
print ":$_:\n" for @$blocks;
```

Comment: He's not parsing it. He's matching it; and a very small subset, at that.

Comment: What do you think is the difference between parsing and matching here? Also, why do you think it's a "very small subset"?

Comment: The question could use some context in order to see whether it's attempted parsing or just matching a small subset.

Comment: Again, why do you think there's a difference here?

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done at all. In general, if you want to parse arbitrary Perl code, you need to be able to execute Perl as well, because `use` and `BEGIN` run at parse time and can affect how the rest of the code is parsed.

Example:

```
use Some::Module;
foo / 1;
is_this_code();
#/;
```

How this is parsed depends on how `foo` is declared. If it's a normal function, it's called with the result of the regex `/ 1;\nis_this_code();\n#/`. If it's declared with a prototype of `()`, the code will divide the return value of `foo` by 1, then call `is_this_code()`.